# Weird behavior when using a queue to store buffer data in producer-consumer multithreading program

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, semaphore

I created a small program where a producer thread creates a random number and pushes it to a stack, then a consumer thread pops the stack and prints out the value to the console. I created 2 semaphores, one semaphore to signal when buffer slots are empty (initialized to `MAX_BUFFER_SLOTS`) and another one to signal when buffer slots are full (initialized to 0). The consumer waits on the `fullSemaphore`, and the producer waits on the `emptySemaphore`. After the consumer/producer threads are signaled, they modify the buffer accordingly using a `bufferMutex`. With the semaphores, the consumer should never try to "consume" unless there is at least one full slot, and the producer should never try to "produce" unless there is at least one empty slot. This seems to be working fine using a stack as my buffer.

The issue is when I try to implement the buffer as a queue. I always hit an exception in `printQueue()` when it tries to print `currentSlot->num`. Based on the printed output (see output below), when the consumer consumes `22` from the buffer, I think it should be setting the size to `1`, not `2` again? And so I think this is messing up the `bufferSize` to be one larger than it actually is, which later causes an invalid access. Not too sure though. I can't tell if I have a bug (I went through the logic several times and don't see anything wrong with it). Or maybe the semaphores somehow are not working properly? I tried using different semaphore libraries, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Not sure if it affects, but I am running my program via Xcode on my Mac.

Here is my program:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

static const char* loggingPrefix = "Multithreading";

#define RAND_OUTPUT_MAX 50
#define MAX_BUFFER_SLOTS 15

// Buffer, implemented as queue
typedef struct slot {
    int num;
    struct slot *next;
}slot_t;
static slot_t* startSlot = NULL;
static slot_t* endSlot = NULL;
static int bufferSize = 0;

// Buffer mutex to make sure only one thread accesses buffer variables at a time
static pthread_mutex_t bufferMutex;

// Buffer empty/full semaphores to signal to producer/consumer when to run
static sem_t *emptySemaphore;
static sem_t *fullSemaphore;

static int shouldProduce(void) {
    return bufferSize < MAX_BUFFER_SLOTS;
}

static int shouldConsume(void) {
    return bufferSize > 0;
}

static void printQueue(void) {
    slot_t *currentSlot = startSlot;
    printf("%s: [ ", loggingPrefix);
    while (currentSlot != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", currentSlot->num);
        currentSlot = currentSlot->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

static void produce(int num) {
    if (shouldProduce()) {
        slot_t *newSlot = (slot_t *)malloc(sizeof(slot_t));
        newSlot->num = num;
        newSlot->next = NULL;
        if (bufferSize == 0) {
            startSlot = newSlot;
            endSlot = newSlot;
        } else {
            endSlot->next = newSlot;
            endSlot = newSlot;
        }
        bufferSize++;
    } else {
        printf("%s: ERROR: Tried to produce while buffer is full!!!\n");
    }
    printQueue();
}

static int consume(void) {
    int ret;
    if (shouldConsume()) {
        slot_t *deletedSlot = startSlot;
        startSlot = deletedSlot->next;
        int deletedNum = deletedSlot->num;
        free(deletedSlot);
        deletedSlot = NULL;
        bufferSize--;
        ret = deletedNum;
    } else {
        printf("%s: ERROR: Tried to consume from an empty buffer!!!\n");
        ret = -1;
    }
    printQueue();
    return ret;
}

static void* produceThread(void* args) {
    while (1) {
        int num = rand() % RAND_OUTPUT_MAX;

        sem_wait(emptySemaphore);
        
        pthread_mutex_lock(&bufferMutex);
        if (shouldProduce()) {
            produce(num);
            printf("%s: Produced %d, size: %d\n", loggingPrefix, num, bufferSize);
        } else {
            printf("%s: Producer skipping %d, size: %d\n", loggingPrefix, num, bufferSize);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bufferMutex);
        
        sem_post(fullSemaphore);
    }
}

static void* consumeThread(void* args) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(fullSemaphore);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&bufferMutex);
        if (shouldConsume()) {
            int num = consume();
            printf("%s: Consumed %d, size: %d\n", loggingPrefix, num, bufferSize);
        } else {
            printf("%s: Consumer waiting, buffer empty, size: %d\n", loggingPrefix, bufferSize);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bufferMutex);

        sem_post(emptySemaphore);
    }
}

#define EMPTY_SEMAPHORE_ID "/emptySemaphore"
#define FULL_SEMAPHORE_ID "/fullSemaphore"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    srand((uint32_t)time(NULL));
    pthread_t producer;
    pthread_t consumer;
    
    // Create the semaphore
    if((emptySemaphore = sem_open(EMPTY_SEMAPHORE_ID, O_CREAT, 0644, MAX_BUFFER_SLOTS)) == SEM_FAILED ||
       (fullSemaphore = sem_open(FULL_SEMAPHORE_ID, O_CREAT, 0644, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Create the threads
    if (pthread_create(&producer, NULL, &produceThread, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("%s: Failed to create producer\n", loggingPrefix);
    }
    if (pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, &consumeThread, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("%s: Failed to create consumer\n", loggingPrefix);
    }
    
    // Wait until the threads finish to exit this function
    if (pthread_join(producer, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("%s: Failed to join producer thread\n", loggingPrefix);
    }
    if (pthread_join(consumer, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("%s: Failed to join consumer thread\n", loggingPrefix);
    }
    
    // Destroy the threads
    if (sem_close(emptySemaphore) == -1 || sem_close(fullSemaphore) == -1) {
        perror("sem_close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (sem_unlink(EMPTY_SEMAPHORE_ID) == -1 || sem_unlink(FULL_SEMAPHORE_ID) == -1) {
        perror("sem_unlink");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the output using the `semaphore.h` library and a queue for the buffer:

```
Multithreading: [ 2 ]
Multithreading: Produced 2, size: 1
Multithreading: [ 2 2 ]
Multithreading: Produced 2, size: 2
Multithreading: [ 2 2 22 ]
Multithreading: Produced 22, size: 2
Multithreading: [ 2 22 0 ]
Multithreading: Produced 0, size: 3
Multithreading: [ 2 22 0 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 2, size: 3
Multithreading: [ 22 0 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 2, size: 2
Multithreading: [ -559120240 Multithreading: [ 1953394534 0 35 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 22, size: 2
Multithreading: [ 35 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 0, size: 1
```

EDIT: I literally copied and pasted Support Ukraine's solution ([ideone.com/apXf6Z](https://ideone.com/apXf6Z)) into my Xcode and it still hit the `exit(1)` in the `printQueue()` function. Could it be due to Xcode, or the fact that I am running this on a Mac (not Windows/Linux) that is causing the program to behave weird like this?

Output:

```html
Multithreading: [ 8 ]
Multithreading: Produced 8, size: 1 cnt: 1
Multithreading: [ 8 8 ]
Multithreading: Produced 8, size: 2 cnt: 2
Multithreading: [ 8 8 37 ]
Multithreading: Produced 37, size: 2 cnt: 3
Multithreading: [ 8 37 42 ]
Multithreading: Produced 42, size: 3 cnt: 4
Multithreading: [ 8 37 42 34 ]
Multithreading: Produced 34, size: 4 cnt: 5
Multithreading: [ 8 37 42 34 33 ]
Multithreading: Produced 33, size: 5 cnt: 6
Multithreading: [ 8 37 42 34 33 15 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 8, size: 6 cnt: 1
Multithreading: [ 37 42 34 33 15 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 8, size: 5 cnt: 2
Multithreading: [ -559054752 Multithreading: [ 42 34 33 15 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 37, size: 4 cnt: 3
Multithreading: [ 34 33 15 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 42, size: 3 cnt: 4
Multithreading: [ 33 15 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 34, size: 2 cnt: 5
Multithreading: [ 15 ]
Multithreading: Consumed 33, size: 1 cnt: 6
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

Comment: Please provide a demonstration of the problem. What you posted doesn't even compile, and issues multiple warnings once I add the missing headers.

Comment: This is why conditional compiling with compiler switches is a bad idea: it makes the code unreadable. Consider solving this with version control instead and by linking different files to the project depending on build. Or simply have multiple projects with some files overlapping.

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far.It compiles for me though, I just copied and pasted the code from my .c file to here. Not sure if I need to include the main function and what not? It's my first time using Stack Overflow to post a question.

Comment: Let me review the consumer updating endSlot, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yeah I totally understand the #if, #else, etc. are messy, I just wanted a way to quickly switch between the different ways of implementing this solution because I wanted to see what method worked/didn't work, just for testing.

Comment: Ok, I removed all the #if, #else, etc. to make it cleaner, hopefully it's easier to read now.

Comment: Also hopefully it compiles now, it shouldn't depend on any header files and what not.

Comment: Oh wow now it works with @SupportUkraine suggestion. In `consume()`, after I set `startSlot = deletedSlot->next` I had to set `endSlot = NULL` if `startSlot == NULL`. Still need to go through the logic to see how this invalid access was affecting my program, but thank you for catching that!

Comment: @SupportUkraine oh that is true, hm that doesn't seem correct, I probably shouldn't post if I don't end up producing/consuming anything, maybe I have a mistake there as well. Let me double check that logic.

Comment: Ya that makes a lot of sense, let me change that and see what happens.

Comment: Hm, not sure what happened, now it's not working again, same error, but I have both changes added (update `endSlot` also in `consume()` and only `sem_post` when it actually produces/consumes).

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions, I will make sure to make all these changes later today and see if I can get it to work. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your solution into my Xcode and it still hit the `exit(1)` in the `printQueue()` function. Could it be due to Xcode, or the fact that I am running this on a Mac (not Windows/Linux) that is causing the program to behave weird like this?

Comment: I updated the question with the output running Support Ukraine's solution.